# 「違いの分かる辛口の人」とはどんな人ですか。

Tags: translation, words, reading-comprehension

So I've decided to watch the original Pokemon series as listening practice. Ran into this sentence where Ash is dreaming about which starter Pokemon to pick:

> [image: https://i.imgur.com/mDQT56A.png]

Charmander is recommended for people who ...?
違いの分かる: knows the difference, so discerning?
辛口: harsh, dry?

Putting the two together I'm guessing it's referring to people who are harshly critical of things. So people who are intimately knowledgeable and critical about which Pokemon are good/bad (i.e. hardcore min-maxers).
Is that about right or am I way off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 違いの分かる: discerning
- 辛口: likes spicy food

I think the narrator associates "spicy" with the hotness of fire. It's somewhat understandable with that in mind, but it's not the most natural thing to say in relation to "fire" either. I think the point is to make the association not too obvious and somewhat mysterious. "People who like fireworks" would be too obvious and boring, for example.

However, 辛口 for harshness can be correct, too. Perhaps the pokemon is recommended to people who like challenges. This makes more sense if choosing it makes the game play harder than the other options. (I don't know if that's true.)

I prefer the first interpretation, but I wouldn't discard the second possibility.

Comment: 一番目のジムはいわタイプで、二番目はみずタイプです。どちらもほのおタイプのヒトカゲには強いんです。

Comment: それなら私が書いた両方の意味で解釈できると思います。